# Eliminating nearest elements from a list or range

Tags: python

So what I have to do is find the smallest number among those that are in the list, and remove from the list both that number and whichever of its current immediate neighbors is larger. This function should repeat until the largest number in the original list gets eliminated  and I have to return the number of times it took to achieve this goal. For example, [1,6,4,2,5,3] would remove element 1 and its current largest neighbor element which is 6, thus reaching the goal in 1 step. My code worked for a list but it did not work when I inputted a range in items. So could anybody help?

```
def elements(items):
 max_value = max(items)
 count = 0
 while max_value in items:
        n = len(items)
        right_of_items = 0
        left_of_items = 0
        min_value = min(items)
        min_value_index = items.index(min_value)
       
        if (min_value_index -1 >= 0):
          left_of_items = items[min_value_index-1]
           
        if (min_value_index+1 < n): 
          right_of_items = items[min_value_index+1]
        
        if left_of_items > right_of_items:
            items.remove(left_of_items)
            items.remove(min_value)
            count += 1 
           
        else:
            items.remove(right_of_items)
            items.remove(min_value)
            count += 1 
          
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with range is that it doesn't support access to a specific item.
So that, you either need to build a list from that range, or use more advanced algorithm which will be able to find the solution in a single pass.

As we won't know the smallest and largest items unless we're analysed the whole list, I guess, there's no such algorithm, that could solve in less than 2 passes, so consider just doing

```py
items = list(items)
```

at the beginning of your function.

---

Also I would suggest to not to store the values of a smallest and largest items themselves. Better store their positions. So that you'll be able to access (and remove) neighbours much more effeciently. Like:

```py
def find_largest_neighbour(lst, pos):
    if pos <= 0:
        return pos + 1
    if pos + 1 >= len(lst):
        return pos - 1
    if lst[pos - 1] <= lst[pos + 1]:
        return pos - 1
    else:
        return pos + 1

def find_min_and_max(lst):
    min_pos = max_pos = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if v < lst[min_pos]:
            min_pos = i
        if v > lst[max_pos]:
            max_pos = i
    return min_pos, max_pos

def solve(lst):
    number_of_iterations = 0
    while True:
        number_of_iterations += 1
        min_pos, max_pos = find_min_and_max(lst)
        max_pos_about = find_largest_neighbour(lst, min_pos)
        if max_pos_about == max_pos:
            # The largest item found about the smallest, we're done
            break
        else:
            # Getting rid of the smallest item and its largest bro 
            del lst[min_pos]
            del lst[max_pos_about]
            # as we used index lookups above, we
            # won't search through the list twice 

    return number_of_iterations
```